# list comprehension using regex conditional

Tags: python, regex, list, list-comprehension, conditional-statements

i have a list of strings.
If any of these strings has a 4-digit year, i want to truncate the string at the end of the year. 
Otherwise I leave the strings alone.

I tried using:

```
    for x in my_strings:   
      m=re.search("\D\d\d\d\d\D",x)  
      if m: x=x[:m.end()]
```

I also tried:

```
my_strings=[x[:re.search("\D\d\d\d\d\D",x).end()] if re.search("\D\d\d\d\d\D",x) for x in my_strings]
```

Neither of these is working.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A sample input/output will be easier to understand for those who doesn't know Python but know REGEX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this seems to work on trivial data:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^(.*(?<=\D)\d{4}(?=\D))(.*)')                         
>>> strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo 1999', 'foo 1999 never see this', 'bar 2010 n 2015', 'bar 20156 see this']
>>> [regex.sub(r'\1', s) for s in strings]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo 1999', 'foo 1999', 'bar 2010', 'bar 20156 see this']
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your only bound on the result string is at the `end()`, so you should be using `re.match()` instead, and modify your regex to:

```
my_expr = r".*?\D\d{4}\D"
```

Then, in your code, do:

```
regex = re.compile(my_expr)
my_new_strings = []
for string in my_strings:
    match = regex.match(string)
    if match:
        my_new_strings.append(match.group())
    else:
        my_new_strings.append(string)
```

Or as a *list comprehension*:

```
regex = re.compile(my_expr)
matches = ((regex.match(string), string) for string in my_strings)
my_new_strings = [match.group() if match else string for match, string in matches]
```

Alternatively, you could use `re.sub`:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(\D\d{4})\D')
new_strings = [regex.sub(r'\1', string) for string in my_strings]
```

Comment: Why does the bound on the result matter for determining wehther one uses re.match() or re.search()?

Also — would you recommend your list comprehension code as a general template for using conditional regex in list comprehensions? What are the downsides to this code pattern?

Comment: @mpacer: `re.match("foo")` is equivalent to `re.search("^foo")`. `match()` always starts at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @mpacer: I think the most succinct pattern is the `re.sub` pattern I've added at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of your usecase, but the following code can give you some hints:

```
import re

my_strings = ['abcd', 'ab12cd34', 'ab1234', 'ab1234cd', '1234cd', '123cd1234cd']

for index, string in enumerate(my_strings):
    match = re.search('\d{4}', string)
    if match:
        my_strings[index] = string[0:match.end()]

print my_strings

# ['abcd', 'ab12cd34', 'ab1234', 'ab1234', '1234', '123cd1234']
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the `\D` behavior (although it wouldn't be too hard to add that in).

Answer (score 0):

You were actually pretty close with the list comprehension, but your syntax is off - you need to make the first expression a "conditional expression" aka `x if <boolean> else y`:

```
[x[:re.search("\D\d\d\d\d\D",x).end()] if re.search("\D\d\d\d\d\D",x) else x for x in my_strings]
```

Obviously this is pretty ugly/hard to read.  There are several better ways to split your string around a 4-digit year.  Such as:

```
[re.split(r'(?<=\D\d{4})\D', x)[0] for x in my_strings]
```